# How to format a table in CSS so that the row of certain columns are shifted downwards by a distance half their row height?

Tags: html, css, row

Probably the solution does not exist or is a hard bone to crack.
I have a table coded like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
    table {
        font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
        font-size:11px;
        color:#333333;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #3A3A3A;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table th {
        border-width: 1px;
        padding: 8px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #3A3A3A;
        background-color: #B3B3B3;
    }
    table td {
        border-width: 1px;
        padding: 8px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #3A3A3A;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
</style>

<title>Table</title>
</head>

<body>

<table>
<thead>
    <tr><th>boundary</th><th>slice</th><th>h_i</th><th>1/2 (h_{i+1}+h_i)</th></tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr><td>0</td><td></td><td>0.00</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>2.26</td><td>1.13</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>2</td><td>4.37</td><td>3.32</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>3</td><td>6.32</td><td>5.35</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>4</td><td>5.74</td><td>6.03</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>4.90</td><td>5.32</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td><td>6</td><td>3.61</td><td>4.25</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td><td>7</td><td>0.00</td><td>1.80</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I want that the table be formatted in CSS so that the rows that belong to the odd columns be shifted half of its height downwards. Such as is shown in the following image.
[Formatting the table in order to have rows shifted downwards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGIC0.png)

Please, do avoid row spanning in the structure of the table. I know it is possible to obtain the solution by spanning four rows for the even columns and two rows for the odd columns. But doing like that is not elegant and I will waste a lot of blank td tags.

The challenge here is to have the solution with pure formatting, with CSS, if a solution exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use transform :

```css
table {
  font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #333333;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #3A3A3A;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table th {
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #3A3A3A;
  background-color: #B3B3B3;
}
table td {
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #3A3A3A;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

:empty {
  opacity:0;
}

tbody tr td:nth-child(even) {
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px #3a3a3a
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>boundary</th>
      <th>slice</th>
      <th>h_i</th>
      <th>1/2 (h_{i+1}+h_i)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>0.00</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2.26</td>
      <td>1.13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>4.37</td>
      <td>3.32</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>6.32</td>
      <td>5.35</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5.74</td>
      <td>6.03</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>4.90</td>
      <td>5.32</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>3.61</td>
      <td>4.25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>0.00</td>
      <td>1.80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Else,witout CSS, use the rowspan attribute and empty cells on the last row too.**

```css
td:empty {
  opacity: 0;
}

table {
  font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #333333;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #3A3A3A;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table th {
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #3A3A3A;
  background-color: #B3B3B3;
}

table td {
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #3A3A3A;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

:empty {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>boundary</th>
      <th>slice</th>
      <th>h_i</th>
      <th>1/2 (h_{i+1}+h_i)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan=2>0</td>
      <td></td>
      <td rowspan=2>0.00</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan=2>1</td>

      <td rowspan=2>2.26</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan=2>1</td>
      <td rowspan=2>1.13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan=2>2</td>
      <td rowspan=2>4.37</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan=2>2</td>
      <td rowspan=2>3.32</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan=2>3</td>
      <td rowspan=2>6.32</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan=2>3</td>
      <td rowspan=2>5.35</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan=2>4</td>
      <td rowspan=2>5.74</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan=2>4</td>
      <td rowspan=2>6.03</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan=2>5</td>
      <td rowspan=2>4.90</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan=2>5</td>
      <td rowspan=2>5.32</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan=2>6</td>
      <td rowspan=2>3.61</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan=2>6</td>
      <td rowspan=2>4.25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan=2>7</td>
      <td rowspan=2>0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan=2>7</td>
      <td rowspan=2>1.80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://html.com/tables/rowspan-colspan/